# sendmail not sending to the cloud (local mail works)

Tags: linux, logs, sendmail, smtp

I'm using a perl module (Mail::Sendmail) which uses `sendmail` to send stuff. It hasn't been working, but hasn't been giving me any errors.

So now I suspect `sendmail`. I tried:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25
mail from:root@localhost.com
rcpt to:max@f33r.com
data
 subject: subject line
 sgiopjsdoigjsd
 sdgsdg

 sdgfsdg
 .
quit
```

I get the "mail accepted for delivery" message, which is what should happen. I wait around for a couple minutes and nothing in my inbox. So I take a look at `/var/log/maillog.3` and it doesn't have anything pertaining to what I just did.

I tried sending mail locally to another user by doing `mail user@localhost.localdomain` and that worked. But still nothing in the logs (which makes me believe the real logs are somewhere else).

**Summing up:**

- Can't send mail to the cloud, but it works locally
- Unknown location of sendmail log file

Comment: Mail::Sendmail uses SMTP to send mail.  `sendmail` is just one of many possible SMTP servers (although it might be the one you have installed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, this sounds like a sendmail.cf problem, as if it's not configured for non-local email, or it's misconfigured.

The file `/var/log/maillog.3` is almost certainly an "old" log file, and therefore, nothing new will get written to it.  You didn't mention what Linux distro, BSD or Unix you're using, but the current log file, the one sendmail currently appends to, is probably named `/var/log/maillog`   If `/var/log/maillog` doesn't exist, you could try stopping and starting sendmail, and seeing if a /var/log/maillog or other file gets created.

Debugging: The old `telnet localhost 25` trick is very useful, as you've found, but you can use something like the old BSD `Mail` program's "-v" option.  Try http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html for source. Using that, you get to see what the SMTP conversation looks like, which can help.

If you're really desperate, you can run sendmail in a debugging mode:

```
sendmail -bt -C /whatever/sendmail.cf
```

You can type in email addresses and see what sendmail does with them.

Comment: I do have a `/var/log/maillog` file but it's empty. It's accompanied by `maillog.1`, `maillog.2` and `maillog.3`. I'll give the debug mode a try next week at work and report back.

Answer (score 1):

By any chance, are you using another MTA (such as exim4)?
Take a look at `/var/log/exim4/*`, that might just be it.